# Azure WAF Rewrite rules for updating port numbers

Tags: url-rewriting, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

I have a server in Azure running two web apps, one on port 443 (IIS), another on 1024 (Apache). Both are https. I have an Azure Application Gateway (WAF v2) in place. I would like to allow requests for subdomain1.domain.com to go through on 443 (which is set-up and working) and requests for subdomain2.domain.com to be re-written to port 1024 internally.

I have tried various combinations of conditions and actions, but cannot get anything to do anything at all, good bad or indifferent!

My current Condition is as follows

```
Type of variable to check: HTTP Header
Header type: Response Header
Header name: Common Header
Common header: Location
Case-sensitive: No
Operator: =
Pattern to match: (https?):\/\/.*subdomain2.domain.com(.*)$
```

My current action is:

```
Re-write type: Response Header
Action type: Set
Header name: Common header
Common header: Location
Header value: https://backendservername.domain.com:1024{http_resp_Location_2}
```

I can't find a combination that does anything at all, nor any examples that show port updates. I've tried using request headers and the host value, but unfortunately that conflicts with the host rewrite in the HTTP Settings that was necessary to get any end to end SSL working.

Thanks in advance.
Matt.

Comment: WAF does not do rewrite its a firewall, the re writes have to happen on your load balancer

Comment: Yes, agreed - but to clarify, I mentioned it's a WAFv2 just to be clear on the Microsoft Azure SKU I am using. The WAFv2 is based upon the Microsoft Azure Application Gateway v2, which also does load balancing etc.